# Integer check not working

Tags: python, variables

This is quite possible the most perplexing piece of code I've ever seen, and i can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it.

```
a = 5
if a == 0 or 1 : 
    print "hi"
```

When run, it prints "hi" which by all means confuses me.
Please provide some insight onto how i can make it not return hi and behave normally. (it should be returning nothing)

Comment: You'll have to check each value separately: `if a == 0 or  a == 1:` or *else* you'll be *short-circuiting* the first condition with an integer.

Comment: It's `if (a == 0) or 1:`.

Comment: `1` evalutes to `True` in Python - so you get `if False or True:` which evaluates to `True`

Comment: can do `if a in (0, 1):`

Comment: You should study operator precedence. Also, if you want to check if a variable is one of some set of values, use `if a in (0, 1):`

Comment: "This is quite possible the most perplexing piece of code I've ever seen". You must not have been programming very long :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 5
if (a == 0) or (a == 1): #changed from if a == 0 or 1
    print ("hi")
#does not print 'hi'
```

Check `a` against `0` and `1` independently.

Comment: It's not that you're wrong; it's just that this answer is already covered in a duplicate.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in this way:

```
  while not a = 5:
          if a in [0, 1]:
              print "Hi"
```